# What is causing airflow webserver to fail and restart on docker for Mac?

Tags: airflow

I am trying to get Airflow running on a local Docker Desktop for Mac installation using the Quick Start instructions for a Docker installation at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html.  The install seems to go correctly, but when I start up the services using `docker-compose up`, all the services launch except for the webserver.  That service starts, but then fails and restarts, over and over.  The log shows this error:

EDIT:  I found the issue in case someone else runs into it.  The default configuration of Docker desktop for Mac doesn't allocate enough memory to run webserver.  I bumped up the memory allocation in Docker, restarted everything, and all was good.

Comment: could you add the error log so that others can benefit from your approach.

Comment: you made my day. Thx!

Comment: As an additional note if you see `airflow_airflow-webserver_1 exited with code 137` in the Docker logs, it means you've not allocated enough memory to Docker.

Answer (score 7):

increasing the memory configuration of the docker worked for me

---

Edit:
Docs for docker configurations on mac: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/

Comment: it is more helpful to add follow up instructions on how to implement the solution/answer.

Comment: Just to add details about how to do that, here is the link that guides how to enter the memory management panel https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/#resources